# How to create nested dynamic form elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I want the select-option and input-text fields to be added once when I click on the Add button.

I've already achieved this. That's okay.

When I click on the **Add Serv** button, the input-text field in the relevant line needs to be added.

Now, every time I click, it assigns a field to each line. Once I click, there are 2 "Services" fields per row. When I click twice, there are 3 "Services" fields in each line.

When I click on the **Remove Serv** button, it deletes one row from each row, showing a similar behavior. How can I ensure that these operations occur for the relevant row?

The "Add serv" and "Remove serv" buttons are not working properly.

```
keyValueFA = new FormArray([this.newKeyValueFG]);
keyServFA = new FormArray([this.newServFG]);

propertyFG = new FormGroup({
  keyValue: this.keyValueFA,
  //serv:this.keyServFA
});


get newKeyValueFG(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    prof: new FormControl(null),
    //serv: new FormControl(null),
  });
}

get newServFG(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    serv: new FormControl(null),
  });
}

get keyValueArrayFGControls(): FormGroup[] {
  return this.keyValueFA.controls as FormGroup[];
}

get keyValueArrayFGControlss(): FormGroup[] {
  return this.keyServFA.controls as FormGroup[];
}

addNewKeyValueFG(): void {
  this.keyValueFA.push(this.newKeyValueFG);
}

addNewServFG(): void {
  this.keyServFA.push(this.newServFG);
}

removeNewKeyValueFG(index: number): void {
  this.keyValueFA.removeAt(index);
}

removeNewServFG(index: number): void {
  this.keyServFA.removeAt(index);
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="propertyFG">
  <div formArrayName="keyValue" *ngFor="let fg of keyValueArrayFGControls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroup]="fg">

      <div class="col-4">

        <select formControlName="prof" width="100%" class="form-control">

          <option *ngFor="let l of professions;" [value]="l._id">
            {{getProfessionNameByLang(l.name)}}
          </option>
        </select>

      </div>

      <div *ngFor="let sr of keyValueArrayFGControlss; let j = index" class="col-4">
        <div [formGroup]="sr">

          <input type="text" formControlName="serv" [id]="'myDiv-' + i+ j" placeholder="Hizmet" />

          <button (click)="removeNewServFG(j)">Remove Serv</button>

        </div>

      </div>
      <button (click)="removeNewKeyValueFG(i)">Remove</button>
      <button (click)="addNewServFG()">Add Serv</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <button (click)="addNewKeyValueFG()">Add</button>
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really it's hard for me understand what do you're trying to do. How it's the object do you want to manage (the structure of your formGroup propertyFG.value)?

Comment: can you rearrange this on stackblitz & also could you mention your expectation in detail, could be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sharing the same `FormArray` instance `keyServFA` for each FormGroup. Instead, each `FormGroup` should have its own `keyServFA`/`services` `FormArray`.

```
  <ng-container formArrayName="services">
    <div
      *ngFor="let sr of serviceControlsByKeyValueFG(i).controls; let j = index"
      class="col-4"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="j">
        <input
          type="text"
          formControlName="serv"
          [id]="'myDiv-' + i+ j"
          placeholder="Hizmet"
        />

        <button (click)="removeNewServFG(i, j)">Remove Serv</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <button (click)="removeNewKeyValueFG(i)">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="addNewServFG(i)">Add Serv</button>
```

When adding, retrieving, or deleting the service `FormGroup`, you should provide the index of `keyValueFG` to get the correct `keyValueFG` `FormGroup`.

```
get newKeyValueFG(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    prof: new FormControl(null),
    services: new FormArray([this.newServFG]),
  });
}

serviceControlsByKeyValueFG(rootIndex: number): FormArray {
  return (this.keyValueFA.controls[rootIndex] as FormGroup).controls[
    'services'
  ] as FormArray;
}

addNewServFG(rootIndex: number): void {
  this.serviceControlsByKeyValueFG(rootIndex).push(this.newServFG);
}

removeNewServFG(rootIndex: number, index: number): void {
  this.serviceControlsByKeyValueFG(rootIndex).removeAt(index);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qfucxq?file=src%2Fmain.ts)